# Use postgres_fdw user mapping with AWS IAM role?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, security, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

In order to execute a query on a local PostgreSQL database (v10.14; Amazon RDS) that fetches data from a remote database, also PostgreSQL (RDS), we're using the foreign data wrapper (FDW) `postgres_fdw` server and user mapping. Currently the user mapping contains user/password credentials for the remote RDS, stored with the user mapping in the local RDS. To become more secure we would like to get rid of the stored credentials.

One way of doing so that we could imagine is using the IAM role of the local RDS to connect to the remote RDS. The question is, is that possible with `postgres_fdw`, are there maybe other FDWs with the same feature set as `postgres_fdw` and allow IAM authentication?

Are there other ways to set up an FDW like this without storing the credentials inside the local RDS?

Comment: Having the same issue now. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: If I remember correctly there was no solution to this very problem. It just faded away after some time as the database setup changed. I'm sorry I can't give you any more than that.